# The checksum value doesn't match for the resource named 'isRecyclableGarden'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, checksum

So I have recently gotten on board with AWS Lambda and I've been working on a bot since yesterday afternoon but now all of a sudden, this is happening. I whenever I go to build the bot or save the intent, I just keep getting the message 'The checksum value doesn't match for the resource named 'isRecyclableGarden'.'

isRecyclableGarden is one of the intents I am using within my code. I can't share the code as it's work code and I am fairly new to this. Any help on how I can work out how to validate the check sum again would be helpful as I cant actually edit or progress with this code!

[Pictured is the problem I am having.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0oio.jpg)

Answer (score 18):

It happens often when your Bot Build version differs from the current Bot version. It should work if you refresh the page and choose the "Latest" from the versions tag.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have edited the post to say I worked this out but thanks for answering, this was the exact problem! Refreshing the page works wonders!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please do mark the answer as correct for future travellers !